# How to avoid warnings for Caliburn Micro Event Aggregator HandleAsync method names?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, caliburn.micro

My problem is simply that if I use Caliburn Micro's Event Aggregator, and implement the interface "IHandle", then that creates a method called "HandleAsync(MyEvent message, CancelleationToken token)".

My problem is that typically those methods are not asynchronous, and don't need marked with "async", or return a Task, therefore really shouldn't have "Async" on the end as they're not asynchronous methods, and raises a warning in Visual Studio.

This isn't causing me any technical problems, it's just irritating to name methods incorrectly just to abide by Caliburn Micro's interface for event aggregator subscription methods.

Simple question is how to either remove the Async from the end of the method name, or otherwise get rid of these warnings?

Thanks

Garry

Comment: What exactly does the warning look like?

Comment: Visual Studio warning CS1998, basically a style issue that you shouldn't have "Async" on the end of method names for methods that are not asynchronous, and a lot of the event aggregator methods are not, they're simple calls to refresh a list or whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately that is not possible with the current implementation of `EventAggregator` in Caliburn Micro.

If you were to check the implementation of EventAggregator in the [github repository](https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro/blob/master/src/Caliburn.Micro.Core/EventAggregator.cs), you would notice that it is searching for method with the specific name.

```
var interfaces = handler.GetType().GetTypeInfo().ImplementedInterfaces
                    .Where(x => x.GetTypeInfo().IsGenericType && x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IHandle<>));

foreach (var @interface in interfaces)
{
  var type = @interface.GetTypeInfo().GenericTypeArguments[0];
  var method = @interface.GetRuntimeMethod("HandleAsync", new[] { type, typeof(CancellationToken) });

  if (method != null)
  {
    _supportedHandlers[type] = method;
  }
}
```

One alternative would be to implement your own version of `IEventAggregator` and introduce two interfaces `IHandle<T>` and `IHandleWithTask<T>` to represent synchronous and asynchronous variants.

Comment: That is what I expected,  perhaps implementing my own is an option here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to [suppress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-suppress-compiler-warnings?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) the warning in your source code.

Right-click on it in the error list and choose Suppress->In Source or Suppress->In Suppression File depending on where you want to insert the `#pragma` directive.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping for a way to actually fix the issue rather than suppress the warning, it's really just one of those things that winds me up rather than an actual technical problem.